# Conflict with jQuery scripts

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, conflict

I have these jQuery scripts in my HTML and they work very well...

```
<script type="text/javascript">
      $(function() {
        $('#iphone').crossSlide({
          sleep: 2,
          fade: 1
        }, [
          { src: 'images/screen1.png' },
          { src: 'images/screen2.png' },
          { src: 'images/screen3.png' }
        ])
      });
    </script>

    <script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $('#features').hide();
        $('#more_features').click(function() {
            $('#features').slideToggle(500);
            return false;
        });
    });
    </script>

    <script type="text/javascript">
    $('a.toTop').click(function() {
        $('html, body').animate({scrollTop: '0px'}, 500);
        return false;
    });
    </script>

    <script type="text/javascript">
    $(function() {
        $('a.contactLink').click(function() {
            $('html, body').animate({scrollTop: '0px'}, 100);
            $('#risposta').hide();
            $('#formName').val('');
            $('#formEmail').val('');
            $('#formSubject').val('');
            $('#formMessage').val('');
            $('#mask').show().fadeTo('', 0.7);
            $('#contact').fadeIn();
            return false;
        });
        $('#mask').click(function() {
            $('#mask, #contact').stop().fadeOut('slow');
        });
    });
    </script>

    <script type="text/javascript">
    $(function() {
        $('a.newsletterLink').click(function() {
            $('html, body').animate({scrollTop: '0px'}, 100);
            $('#mce-responses').hide();
            $('#mce-NAME').val('');
            $('#mce-EMAIL').val('');
            $('#mask').show().fadeTo('', 0.7);
            $('#mc_embed_signup').fadeIn();
            return false;
        });
        $('#mask').click(function() {
            $('#mask, #mc_embed_signup').stop().fadeOut('slow');
        });
    });
    </script>

    <script type="text/javascript">
     $(document).ready(function(){
        $("#formSend").click(function(){

            var valid = '';
            var name = $("#formName").val();
            var mail = $("#formEmail").val();
            var subject = $("#formSubject").val();
            var messaggio = $("#formMessage").val();

            if (name.length<1) {
                valid += '<span>Please, fill name field.</span><br />';
            }
            if (!mail.match(/^([a-z0-9._-]+@[a-z0-9._-]+\.[a-z]{2,4}$)/i)) {
                valid += '<span>Please, enter a valid email address.</span><br />';
            }
            if (subject.length<1) {
                valid += '<span>Please, fill subject field.</span><br />';
            }

            if (valid!='') {
                $("#risposta").fadeIn("slow");
                $("#risposta").html("<span><b>Error:</b></span><br />"+valid);
                $("#risposta").css("background-color","#ffc0c0");
            }
            else {
                var datastr ='name=' + name + '&mail=' + mail + '&subject=' + subject + '&messaggio=' + encodeURIComponent(messaggio);
                $("#risposta").css("display", "block");
                $("#risposta").css("background-color","#FFFFA0");
                $("#risposta").html("<span>Sending message...</span>");
                $("#risposta").fadeIn("slow");
                setTimeout("send('"+datastr+"')",2000);
            }
            return false;
        });
    });
    function send(datastr){
        $.ajax({    
            type: "POST",
            url: "contactForm.php",
            data: datastr,
            cache: false,
            success: function(html) {
            $("#risposta").fadeIn("slow");
            $("#risposta").html('<span>Message successfully sent!</span>');
            $("#risposta").css("background-color","#e1ffc0");
            setTimeout('$("#risposta").fadeOut("slow")',2000);
            }
        });
    }
    </script>
```

Now I added a newsletter form that uses Mailchimp service. To use it I must use a jQuery script but when I add it in the HTML, other scripts don't work! In `<head></head>` tags I have these scripts:

```
<script src="jquery-1.4.4.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="jquery.cross-slide.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="http://downloads.mailchimp.com/js/jquery.validate.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="http://downloads.mailchimp.com/js/jquery.form.js" type="text/javascript"</script>
<!-- Using a newer version 
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.2.6/jquery.min.js"></script> -->
```

Finally, this is jQuery script for the newsletter (I mustn't change this!):

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var fnames = new Array();var ftypes = new Array();fnames[0]='EMAIL';ftypes[0]='email';fnames[1]='NAME';ftypes[1]='text';var err_style = '';
    try{
        err_style = mc_custom_error_style;
    } catch(e){
        err_style = '';
    }
    var mce_jQuery = jQuery.noConflict(true);
    mce_jQuery(document).ready( function($) {
      var options = { errorClass: 'mce_inline_error', errorElement: 'div', errorStyle: err_style, onkeyup: function(){}, onfocusout:function(){}, onblur:function(){}  };
      var mce_validator = mce_jQuery("#mc-embedded-subscribe-form").validate(options);
      options = { url: 'http://matthewlabs.us2.list-manage.com/subscribe/post-json?u=88d77c3091b8c0deb9fb740c6&id=2de218cbc7&c=?', type: 'GET', dataType: 'json', contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                    beforeSubmit: function(){
                        mce_jQuery('#mce_tmp_error_msg').remove();
                        mce_jQuery('.datefield','#mc_embed_signup').each(
                            function(){
                                var txt = 'filled';
                                var fields = new Array();
                                var i = 0;
                                mce_jQuery(':text', this).each(
                                    function(){
                                        fields[i] = this;
                                        i++;
                                    });
                                mce_jQuery(':hidden', this).each(
                                    function(){
                                        if ( fields[0].value=='MM' && fields[1].value=='DD' && fields[2].value=='YYYY' ){
                                            this.value = '';
                                        } else if ( fields[0].value=='' && fields[1].value=='' && fields[2].value=='' ){
                                            this.value = '';
                                        } else {
                                            this.value = fields[0].value+'/'+fields[1].value+'/'+fields[2].value;
                                        }
                                    });
                            });
                        return mce_validator.form();
                    }, 
                    success: mce_success_cb
                };
      mce_jQuery('#mc-embedded-subscribe-form').ajaxForm(options);

    });
    function mce_success_cb(resp){
        mce_jQuery('#mce-success-response').hide();
        mce_jQuery('#mce-error-response').hide();
        if (resp.result=="success"){
            mce_jQuery('#mce-'+resp.result+'-response').show();
            mce_jQuery('#mce-'+resp.result+'-response').html(resp.msg);
            mce_jQuery('#mc-embedded-subscribe-form').each(function(){
                this.reset();
            });
        } else {
            var index = -1;
            var msg;
            try {
                var parts = resp.msg.split(' - ',2);
                if (parts[1]==undefined){
                    msg = resp.msg;
                } else {
                    i = parseInt(parts[0]);
                    if (i.toString() == parts[0]){
                        index = parts[0];
                        msg = parts[1];
                    } else {
                        index = -1;
                        msg = resp.msg;
                    }
                }
            } catch(e){
                index = -1;
                msg = resp.msg;
            }
            try{
                if (index== -1){
                    mce_jQuery('#mce-'+resp.result+'-response').show();
                    mce_jQuery('#mce-'+resp.result+'-response').html(msg);            
                } else {
                    err_id = 'mce_tmp_error_msg';
                    html = '<div id="'+err_id+'" style="'+err_style+'"> '+msg+'</div>';

                    var input_id = '#mc_embed_signup';
                    var f = mce_jQuery(input_id);
                    if (ftypes[index]=='address'){
                        input_id = '#mce-'+fnames[index]+'-addr1';
                        f = mce_jQuery(input_id).parent().parent().get(0);
                    } else if (ftypes[index]=='date'){
                        input_id = '#mce-'+fnames[index]+'-month';
                        f = mce_jQuery(input_id).parent().parent().get(0);
                    } else {
                        input_id = '#mce-'+fnames[index];
                        f = mce_jQuery().parent(input_id).get(0);
                    }
                    if (f){
                        mce_jQuery(f).append(html);
                        mce_jQuery(input_id).focus();
                    } else {
                        mce_jQuery('#mce-'+resp.result+'-response').show();
                        mce_jQuery('#mce-'+resp.result+'-response').html(msg);
                    }
                }
            } catch(e){
                mce_jQuery('#mce-'+resp.result+'-response').show();
                mce_jQuery('#mce-'+resp.result+'-response').html(msg);
            }
        }
    }
    </script>
```

Why other scripts don't work? Can you help me?
Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved this problem by deleting this reference from `<head></head>` tags:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.2.6/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Also I also changed this line of code in Mailchimp script:

```
var mce_jQuery = jQuery.noConflict();
```

with this:

```
var mce_jQuery = jQuery;
```

Thanks a lot to all! ;)

Comment: Nice! Although I don't see why this works *without* noConflict... Anyway, good to hear it was fixed :)

Answer (score 2):

You can't use two versions of jQuery on the same page. You will have to make both scripts work with one version (preferably the newer one).

I would try removing the reference to 1.2.6 first and see what happens.

Answer (score 1):

I'd recommend using Firebug to track down what exactly is the error that's causing this to not work. Then, once you see the error message, this will be much easier to troubleshoot.

Comment: Can you explain me how to do this? Thanks :)